# VB .Net to PHP - Get user windows login on Intranet

Tags: php, vb.net, windows, intranet

I have a website on intranet which can be accessed remotely. 
I can get the username of the person PC in VB.net using `Page.User.Identity.Name`. Can something similar be done in PHP?

I have used couple of methods that show windows username but that it shows for server not the user accessing the website in INTRANET.
Any help?

Comment: Is the login handled by Active Directory?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm assuming your login is being handled by Active Directory, in which case you could use the PHP LDAP (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) to achieve what you want.

You can find more detail on it here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php

You'll have to make sure you've enabled the LDAP module in PHP and when you have you should be able to implement it.

There's a good example that I've used in the past here:

https://www.exchangecore.com/blog/how-use-ldap-active-directory-authentication-php/

Hope that helps!